# Directory.Move function don't work in server

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I'd like to move a folder to a different folder in server. In local, my codes works successfully. But in live host, It don't work. Is it related about permissions?

Code sample

```
string from = Server.MapPath(MainRoot + values[1].ToString());
string to = Server.MapPath(MainRoot + newFolderPath);
Directory.Move(from, to);
```

Comment: What exception do you get?

Comment: What exception do you get?

Comment: I can't debug it in live. But I can say that, It doesn't gives error. But don't move the folder. (don't rename the folder name)

Comment: You can add a try-catch block around your program, then write the exception message to a text file, if you can't debug it live.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can not debug it in server, just try to add some validations in code to check whats happening. Do something like this:

```
try
   {
     string from = Server.MapPath(MainRoot + values[1].ToString());
     string to = Server.MapPath(MainRoot + newFolderPath);

     if(!Directory.Exists(from) || !Directory.Exists(to))
     {
       Throw new Exception("One of the directories doesn't exist");
     }

     Directory.Move(from, to); 
   }  
   Catch(Exception ex)
   {
     File.WriteAllText("Error.txt", ex.Message);
   }
```

After execution check the Error.txt to see what happened. It will throw an exception 
if one of the directories don't exist and it will throw an exception too if the IO
operation could not be done for permisiones. Just check the log.

**EDIT**:

Now that you have found the exception, create the directories at runtime:

```
 if(!Directory.Exists(from))
 {
    Directory.Create(from);
 }

 if(!Directory.Exists(to))
 {
     Directory.Create(to);
 }
```

Comment: Don't we expect the `to` directory to not exist? If it does exist you would get an error saying "Cannot rename as a folder with that name already exists" or similar? Therefore your check `If(!Directory.Exists(from) || !Directory.Exists(to))` should just be `if(!Directory.Exists(from))` (Also with a small if)

Comment: I wrote it on cellphone. Gonna change it. Thanks

Comment: This are only validations to check what is happening not for production code

Comment: @ Carlos Landeras; Error is : 'System.Exception: One of the directories doesn't exist'

Comment: Perfect then, you found the problem. now you can create directories in runtime. I update my question check it out